# NullPointerException on String Array Declaration

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have been attempting to declare an array but there is this NullPointer that comes up and prevents me from continuing. Also, I do not have access to LogCat because my Android Version now requires root for that. I am developing purely on a device with only AIDE.

I cannot implicitly paste code here because my device will not allow, so I have my codes put into PasteBin pages.

[MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/6CkkTTCg)
It is at line 45 of the above paste that the NullPointer turns up on

[AppFiles.java](http://pastebin.com/zGvSqWAx)
This is the File that is being referenced with the `MainActivity` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob. Really tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't initialized an Array object for `itemStrings`

replace your code `public static String[] itemStrings;` with this,

```
 public static String[] itemStrings = new String[Your_Array_Length];
```

Comment: Thank you. Fixed my horrible null Pointer but since I need the Array to be dynamic I couldn't set it up exactly like what you gave. I did public static String[] itemStrings = new String [] {}

Comment: @user3801378 Don't use dynamic arrays.  Yeuch.  Try `ArrayList` or similar.  Read about Java generics.

Comment: good eye, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

I state the obvious: One of your file types is not there and you get the NPE for that.

The basic issue is that you return null in your return*() methods instead of an empty File[] array. So basically try that:

```
// just one of the methods picked as an example
public static File[] returnAssignments() {
    Assignments assignments = new Assignments();
    if (assignments.filePath.exists()) {
        return assignments.filePath.listFiles();
    }
    return new File[0];
}
```

That would prevent your `AppFiles.getFileCount(type)` to throw an NPE if no file for that type was found.

Comment: Even with your change

Comment: the other answer found the issue, but you still need my change to prevent another possible NPE.

Comment: @WarranFaith already taken care of